# What card game is this? 3 cards per player; always redraw from stack until end

Tags: identify-this-game

A friend of mine introduced a card game to me she only knows by the name "Schweinemauzen" (we're in Germany, literally maybe "pig's meow"). Surprisingly, googling this word doesn't yield a single result. Maybe someone can help me in identifying the game if I give some basic rules:

- Deck: usually standard 52-card deck, but can be played with 36 cards.
- 2-5 or even more players. First with no cards left wins.
- Dealing cards:

  - 3 rounds of 1 card, face down, per player; they are arranged side-by-side,
  - 3 rounds of 1 card, face up, per player, each laid on top of one dealt before,
  - finally, 3 rounds of 1 card, face down, per player, which the players pick up.
  - The rest is kept as a stack.
- Gameplay:

  - Some similarities to [Durak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durak).
  - A player plays one or more cards of the same rank.
  - The next player has to play one or more cards of the same or a higher rank.
  - If someone cannot play, they have to pick up all cards which were played before.
  - Ranks 2, 7, and 10 are special, they can be used to match an Ace and/or remove all cards on the "played" stack from the game, so that the next player who can't play doesn't have to pick those up.
  - Each player immediately redraws from the stack after they played so that they have 3 cards.
  - When the stack is empty, and no cards are left on the hand of a player, they use their face-up cards to play.
  - When those are empty, the face-down cards are used to play, at which point the game becomes quite random.

Here you see the stack, the played cards stack next to it, and face-down/face-up cards for two players:

[image: Schweinemauzen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what the international name for the game is but we've always called it "[Shithead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shithead_(card_game))", a fun game the face down cards keep the end game close and stops a runaway winner.

Answer (score 1):

We call this game "Lucky". The 2 resets the pile to a low number and a 10 makes the pile go away. I haven't heard about the version using a 7 card for something. But I have heard a version where and 8 card triggers a reverse turn order, and that is good for a four player game so you are not always following the same person (makes things more interesting).